# How to convert ListItemCollection to List(of object)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have defined a class like

```
Public Class MyClass
 Public Type1 As Integer
 Public Type2 As float
End Class
```

How can I convert a ListItemCollection to a list(of MyClass) ?

Comment: @user1460625 & AVD: Look at the tags, says asp.net ...

Comment: @Quandary that tag was added after AVD's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyClass` is keyword and `float` type in VB.NET is expressed via `Single` alias (System.Single)

```
Public Class Item
   Public Type1 As Integer
   Public Type2 As Single
End Class
```

I've construct the collection with *sample* data.

```
Dim cl As New ListItemCollection
cl.Add(New ListItem("1", "1.2"))
cl.Add(New ListItem("2", "2.3"))
cl.Add(New ListItem("3", "3.4"))

Dim lst = From ele In cl Select New  _
                    Item With
                     {
                         .Type1 = Integer.Parse(ele.Text),
                         .Type2 = Single.Parse(ele.Value)
                     }

For Each ele As Item In lst
    Response.Write("<br/>  " & ele.Type1 & " " & ele.Type2)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim x As New List(of [MyClass])

For Each y as [MyClass] in ListItemCollectionInstance.Items

    if (y.Selected)
         x.Add(y)
Next y
```

Using Linq:

```
Dim selectedItems As List(Of [MyClass]) = ListItemCollectionInstance.Items.Cast(Of [MyClass])().Where(Function(itm) itm.Selected = True).ToList()
```